# Is it possible to have conditional flow in the NServiceBus Saga?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

I am new to NServiceBus & its Saga... is it possible to implement conditional flow in the sagas? 
saga:
s->a->b->e
At 'a', i should be able make a choice whether to go b or new state c.
From 'c' again i should reach e

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes.

Saga is a coordinator of the process flow. Based on the state, send a message of one or another type that is handled by the saga to get to one or another state.

Comment: thank you Sean.. could you please point me to any sample, if you know of any, that does this. Iam new to this.

Comment: Absolutely @user441380. [On-premises showcase](https://docs.particular.net/samples/showcase/on-premises/) sample is a good starting point as it can be pulled down and debugged in Visual Studio. It has a sales saga that accepts an order that can be cancelled. If order is not cancelled, it's places/provisioned. Otherwise it will go into cancelled state and nothing will be provisioned.